# How to Switch control to newly opened tab? Selenium Webdriver-chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();




 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='socialicon']/a["+i+"]/img")).click();


 ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());


 newTab.remove(oldTab);

driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(0));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pagelet_loggedout_sign_up']/div/a[1]/span")).click();
```

'  i am not able to switch my control over the new tab through the above code. please help me correcting the same.
'